# Reclassifying multiple rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, reclassify

I have 163 rasters, each one representing the least-cost path from a source to multiple destination locations. I would like to reclassify each raster in order for the cells representing the path to have value 1. I want to do that since I am planning to sum all the rasters up and to use a color scale that would make evident (i.e., more intense color) where paths overlap.

Now, the problem is that I do not know how to reclassify the rasters in a single operation. I am wondering:

(A) can the "iterate rasters" function in the ModelBuilder facility be used for my purpose (and if it can, how?);

(B) how can the Reclassify tools in Arcgis 10.1 be put to work in conjunction with "iterate raster"?

Furthermore, I anticipate that an additional issue would be that the rasters have not the same values. In some of them, the values span from 1 to 32, in other ones from 2 to 28.

Comment: So what do you want the cells to be that are not the path, zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution to my own issue. I have used "iterate raster" in Model Builder. The INPUT of the "iterate raster" routine is the folder containing the 163 rasters. Then, the output of the routine (i.e., each raster through which the routine goes) goes as input into the *Raster Calculator*. In the output of the raster calculator, I put something like pt%Name%: the first bit is the prefix which will show up in each output raster, plus a suffix which is given by the variable %Name% which is the name of the each corresponding input raster. As for the operation implemented in Raster Calculator, for my specific purpose (since I needed each raster to be set to 1), I divided each input raster by itself.