# Summing multiple rasters using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, grids-sum

This is a question related to an earlier one of mine ([Reclassifying multiple rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225326/reclassifying-multiple-rasters-in-arcgis-desktop)). I want to sum up 162 rasters: I tried to load them all into ArcMAP in order to eventually use Raster Calculator, but I have 2 issues:

1. ArcMap seems to get stuck as I try to load hundreds of rasters;
2. I would be forced to write by hand a very long sum into Raster Calculator.

Is there a way to circumvent those issues, i.e. to summing all the rasters without Raster Calculator and/or without writing a very long sum formula?

Comment: Cell statistics does it on the fly

Answer (score 3):

Try **Mosaic to New Raster** with method sum for overlaying rasters. You can select layers, don't have to write long expression.